Do we stress on the auxiliary verb in a Yes-No question?
A general rule of sentence stress is that we don't often stress on auxiliary verbs. However, in a video I saw on Youtube regarding this topic, the teacher said that in Yes-No questions, we do stress on them.

Do you like her?

I wonder why do is stressed in this sentence. Besides, is there any other exception that you can think of when we stress on auxiliary verbs?

I finally found the timestamp in question (12:00—would have been nice to give it). Frankly, the teacher's advice is bewildering. She acknowledges that it's "a bit cheeky" and seems to contradict earlier advice. She asserts that in the question "Do you like her," both "do" and "like" are stressed. I would argue that the way she speaks it disproves her; "do" doesn't sound significantly stressed to me. I think she's devoting more attention to the response, "Yes, I do," in which there's no question that "do" will be stressed.
If there's any way to argue that the normal way of saying "Do you like her" contains a stress on "do," then we must agree that not all stresses are equal. If "do" has any stress as compared to "you," "like" has noticeably more.
Now, one point that as far as I can tell isn't addressed in this video is that we can alter the normal stresses, stress things that normally aren't, to change meaning. We could apply very strong stress to "do," ("DO you like her?") and it would emphasize the questioning nature of the sentence. It might be appropriate in a context like: "Of course, you don't like her. Wait—DO you like her?" See Daniel's answer, showing that you could stress any word in the sentence and change the meaning each time.
Earlier in the video, the teacher said that we stress "affirmative auxiliary verbs." I wasn't sure what this meant and Googled it; the point I take away is: We normally wouldn't bother to stress an auxiliary verb ("I am reading this book"), but we might do so if we're emphasizing an affirmative—that is, if giving this sentence as the answer to a yes/no question, or insisting in an argument when someone has said the opposite ("I AM reading this book!").

Sorry about the timestamp. I'll remember to include it next time. Based on your answer, there seems to be no clear reason why the teacher advised students that way; it's kinda strange, isn't it? Do you think there might be a transatlantic difference here?

@AnIELTSLearner Mm, I'm not sure there's any BrE/AmE difference. I'd look for another source saying the same thing before worrying about it.

I don't hear much of a stress on do either. Perhaps in relation to you, but not in relation to like .  But you could be stressed in another context:  "Your twin BROther deTESTs her. But do YOU like her?"

The stress depends on the meaning.

Do you like her?

She thinks you like her. Is it actually a fact that you do?

Do you like her?

as opposed to any other emotion about her.
And of course you could emphasise other words:

Do you like her?

as opposed to that other girl?

Do you like her?

I do, but do you?
